# Autorelease for CGMutablePathRef?

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics

I am developing for iphone. I want to creating a mutable path via CGPathCreateMutable(), and I want to return it out of the function which creates it. I'm suppose to call a CGPathRelease() when I'm done with it. But since I'm returning it I wish to autorelease it. Since Quartz path is a C code (and doesn't look like an objective C object), is it correct that I cannot call autorelease on it?

Edit:
For others who stumble upon this question, the below advise is for C functions returning Core foundation objects only. For objective C methods returning Core foundation objects,  see [Ownership regarding to returned Quartz objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901942/ownership-regarding-to-returned-quartz-objects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct.  Autorelease pools exist in the Foundation layer and above (AppKit/UIKit, etc).  They don't exist for CoreFoundation/CoreGraphics objects.

The simple way around this is to rename your function.  If your function is currently named:

```
CGMutablePathRef myAwesomePath(params...);
```

Then you should rename it to:

```
CGMutablePathRef createMyAwesomePath(params...);
```

so that you are safe to return an object with a +1 retain count by following the [Create rule](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029).

Comment: By `CHMutablePathRef` do you mean `CGMutablePathRef`?

Comment: But can you autorelease it by casting it to NSObject?