# Ownership regarding to returned Quartz objects

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics

I have recently asked about autoreleasing a returned quartz object:
[Autorelease for CGMutablePathRef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819548/autorelease-for-cgmutablepathref)

Dave DeLong answered my question that there is no autorelease for quartz (or any NS foundation objects) and I should use the [Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). However the naming convention on the document says,

> The Core Foundation naming conventions, in particular use of the word “create”, only apply to C functions that return Core Foundation objects. Naming conventions for Objective-C methods are governed by the Cocoa conventions, irrespective of whether the method returns a Core Foundation or Cocoa object.

By this account since my function is a message in an objective C object it doesn't seem proper to name it createSomething. I still want to return this object. What's the best way to approach this? Should I use the [Get Rule](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW1) and then have the caller explicitly retain it? But this is not within Cocoa convention. What's the proper way to handle this?

Comment: When I said there was no autorelease for CF objects, there isn't, *unless you can toll-free bridge them to their Cocoa counterparts*.  Just to clear up the confusion. :)

Comment: Thanks. It makes me wonder what casting really does underneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you should return an autoreleased object from an Objective-C method that returns a new object. It's easy enough to do this with Core Foundation objects. For example, take this basic class method:

```
+ (CFURLRef)appleWebsiteURL
{
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL,CFSTR("http://apple.com"),NULL);
    return (CFURLRef)[NSMakeCollectable(url) autorelease];
}
```

Note that the above code will work in both a garbage-collected and reference-counted environment. If you're on the iPhone, you might need to do:

```
return (CFURLRef)[(NSObject*)url autorelease];
```

Comment: Do you mean autorelease is available after casting to NSObject * and it will still be at work when you cast it back?

Comment: Yes. Core Foundation objects can be autoreleased.